# Add area behind a single point on line chart in echarts

Tags: javascript, echarts

I need to render the area behind a single point on Echarts.
Currently, the area is visible only when I hover over the point on the chart:

[image: echart markArea hover over tooltip]

I have used markArea property for the rest of the highlighted areas, but am at a loss for how to do this with just one point. Is it possible to offset the start and end of the markAreas somehow, relative to the dates on the xAxis?

I have created a [codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/bold-monad-y8r69h).
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/bold-monad-y8r69h

Comment: You have full control over the markArea coordiantes. Given you know which point should be marked beforehand you can compute the size of it. (fyi codepen is stuck on "Initializing Vs Code.." for me)

Comment: @MatthiasMertens Thanks for the reply, I've updated the link to the code sandbox.
Would it still be possible to use the start and end dates for the markArea, or I would have to divide the x-axis by all the points and use coordinates to create the markAreas?

Comment: I do not quite understand the question. I added an answer since the example link is too long for a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Best I can currently think of is using a second category axis with double the number of categories as the main axis and `show: false` to draw the areas.

[Example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-simple&code=MYewdgzgLgBAJgQygmBeGBtDByATABlwBYBafARjPOwBpyBWfAXRsz0NIrN1plwGZmrHAWJUy_WrmIs2ozpXxEp5AByyRHcfnq1y_ehvZiu-AGx6iAdiPztVqWeZMA3AChQkWHACW0BGDAAKZoMAgATkEIABoAwiAg4XAQABT0AJTubiAADlA-4KEA3m4wMAAeAILlfgBcmKVlMEVQAJ45QfXYwEhBAOaJrdgAvjSNZS3tnTDdvQPhQ6yIyPWV4eEIrQB0AGbhIAC2KUUANkFgfVAAFvXLCFtnF9cwAFR8w-msEFcgAO71OwQJwgQWGjRYjVa1TqzVGjRB4R8QQg9Qw42a6LKbQ6XROPjAQVomPgSAQt1JYyaMDhVJKVKxU1x-MJlPpVRqEAAkmA4EFyvVyKyqQcIgBrNZRep0-llO6o4lUjBFdkw3z-QJBDDMUbNFUo-B-ZAajDkJjDJgKmAWmVgqm2q1uYZZNw7ACugXyhQiUTiCSSqXxvPK6QxZUiUFd4TAmBSgb5rz4nxgsZ58beuBDAGoYKb3MMgA):

```js
const data = [['2024-01-01',150], ['2024-01-02', 230], ['2024-01-03',224], ['2024-01-04',218], ['2024-01-05',135], ['2024-01-06',147], ['2024-01-07',260]];
const distance = areaXCoords(5);

option = {
  xAxis: [
    {type: 'category'},
    {type: 'category', data: Array.from({length: data.length * 2}), show: false}
  ],
  yAxis: {},
  series: [
    {
      type: 'line',
      data: data,
    },
    {
      type: 'line',
      xAxisIndex: 1,
      markArea: {
        data: [
          [{xAxis: distance[0]}, {xAxis: distance[1]}]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
};


function areaXCoords(index) {
  return [(index * 2), (index * 2) + 1];
}
```

---

Previous answer for time axis:

Heres a small [example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-simple&code=MYewdgzgLgBAJgQygmBeGBtDByATABlwBYBafARjPOwBpyBWfAXRsz0NIrN1plwGZmrHAWJUy_WrmIs2ozpXxEp5AByyRHcfnq1y_ehvZiu-AGx6iAdiPztVqWeZMA3AChQkWHACW0BGDAAKZoMAAWCAA2AGYAIn7IgUEAKiAAckE-AOZhAEYgAK4AThAAFEQAlO5uIAAOUD7goQDebjAwAB4Agh1-AFwwre3tUACetUED2A0AtkG0bTAAvjSLoz39gyuLEEFFPkEQAxiL7UPDI-OTMNiRPmDzqxftiMgDrwhPzzMIRQDWXSKQQQA3Oz3gSBBmFO4MwzW6vSO8ASAWCGGYK0GCM2vn8SQw5CYSyYMIuJPBSxhlPaJKW1WiBUCDSaERi8TxwVSGWyeUKJVK9zgQQ6FUGi080E6oViSCCADpar9dqUHgB3GAyqBBUofDCC4VMdFMCpVcXgSWRILRWDoTXyxUlbVqjWynWQvVgIUdGAkGCEo0m9ztCWwfY5G0urUKpVOoLqu1u5Aer0wADUfsNzBNiyBUGKYEw3t9pVKRZglutooA9HwKqxvamS2GwrBfSKYDXcBVaUA):

```js
const data = [['2024-01-01',150], ['2024-01-02', 230], ['2024-01-03',224], ['2024-01-04',218], ['2024-01-05',135], ['2024-01-06',147], ['2024-01-07',260]];
const distance = halfDistanceToNeighbours(4);

option = {
  xAxis: {
    type: 'time',
  },
  yAxis: {},
  series: [
    {
      type: 'line',
      data: data,
      markArea: {
        data: [
          [{xAxis: distance[0]}, {xAxis: distance[1]}]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
};

// this will not work for index 0 and -1
function halfDistanceToNeighbours(index) {
  const x = Date.parse(new Date(data[index][0]));
  const left = Date.parse(new Date(data[index - 1][0]));
  const right = Date.parse(new Date(data[index + 1][0]))
  return [x - ((x - left) / 2), x +((right - x) / 2)]
}
```

Does this answer your question?

Comment: This answer is quite helpful. Do you know if its possible to do the same with xAxis of type "category'? It seems not possible to input [0.5, 0], [1.5, 300] to set a markArea around the point at index 1. I have set the xAxis, which is a time axis to type "category" because I need the points evenly spaced out. Do you know if it is possible to set it to "time" (like you have) but still have each point equidistant to each other?

Comment: Thank you! Both answers are very helpful for understanding how to work with echarts!